# Duplicate whole method via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

I often use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to copy one line of the code.

Is there a keyboard shortcut in IDEA where I can put a caret on the method name and pressing the shortcut combination duplicate the whole method? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> does not help in such case.

Comment: You can try a Macro with the following actions: Collapse, Duplicate, Expand. Duplicate will copy the complete collapsed method. Then you can assign a shortcut for this macro.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Until IDEA does not get a built-in feature like this, you can use this approach (it's pretty quick):

1. Put caret on the method name line or anywhere inside the method itself
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Minus</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Plus</kbd>

Or make a Macro like @CrazyCoder suggested.

Comment: What is `Ctrl` + `Minus` / `Ctrl` + `Plus` doing on your computer??

Answer (score 3):

You can use first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to select method. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate selected lines.